# Convert Vec<String> into a slice of &str in Rust?

Tags: string, vector, reference, rust, ownership

Per [Steve Klabnik's writeup in the pre-Rust 1.0 documentation on the difference between `String` and `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/guide-strings.html#string-vs.-&str), in Rust you should use `&str` unless you really need to have ownership over a `String`. Similarly, it's recommended to use references to slices (`&[]`) instead of `Vec`s unless you really need ownership over the `Vec`.

I have a `Vec<String>` and I want to write a function that uses this sequence of strings and it doesn't need ownership over the `Vec` or `String` instances, should that function take `&[&str]`? If so, what's the best way to reference the `Vec<String>` into `&[&str]`? Or, is this coercion overkill?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can create a function that accepts both `&[String]` and `&[&str]` using the [`AsRef` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html):

```
fn test<T: AsRef<str>>(inp: &[T]) {
    for x in inp { print!("{} ", x.as_ref()) }
    println!("");
}

fn main() {
    let vref = vec!["Hello", "world!"];
    let vown = vec!["May the Force".to_owned(), "be with you.".to_owned()];
    test(&vref);
    test(&vown);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer the OP was looking for, as it allows using the slice without an unnecessary allocation. This approach is even more useful when accepting a slice of `AsRef<Path>` - you want the function to accept all of `&[&str]`, `&[String]`, `&[Path]`, and `&[PathBuf]`, without allocating new memory.

Comment: One sad thing is if you're trying to take a `Option<&[T]>` you can't just pass a `None` without specifying a concret type

Answer (score 21):

This is actually impossible without either memory allocation or per-element call<sup>1</sup>.

Going from `String` to `&str` is not just viewing the bits in a different light; `String` and `&str` have a different memory layout, and thus going from one to the other requires creating a new object. The same applies to `Vec` and `&[]`

Therefore, whilst you can go from `Vec<T>` to `&[T]`, and thus from `Vec<String>` to `&[String]`, you cannot directly go from `Vec<String>` to `&[&str]`. Your choices are:

- either accept `&[String]`
- allocate a new `Vec<&str>` referencing the first `Vec`, and convert *that* into a `&[&str]`

As an example of the allocation:

```
fn usage(_: &[&str]) {}

fn main() {
    let owned = vec![String::new()];

    let half_owned: Vec<_> = owned.iter().map(String::as_str).collect();

    usage(&half_owned);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Using generics and the `AsRef<str>` bound as shown in [@aSpex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5138648/aspex)'s answer you get a slightly more verbose function declaration with the flexibility you were asking for, but you do have to call `.as_ref()` in all elements.*

Comment: Thanks, Matthieu. For my case right now, I think I'll go with `&[String]` since I imagine allocating a new `Vec<&str>` incurs extra work.

Comment: @DonRowe: It incurs an extra allocation (O(1) but potentially expensive) + conversion (O(n)).