# Why does format! produce an error when it's the first element of an AsRef slice?

Tags: generics, vector, rust, reference, macros

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180422/6923555), consider a function which accepts a `Vec`/slice of `String`/`&str`:

```rust
fn foo<S: AsRef<str>>(list: &[S]) {
    for s in list.iter() {
        println!("{}", s.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(&["abc", "def"]);
    foo(&["abc", &format!("def {}", 99)]);
    foo(&[&format!("def {}", 99), "abc"]); // error
}
```

In the last call, I receive the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |     foo(&[&format!("def {}", 99), "abc"]);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found array `[&str; 2]`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&String]`
              found reference `&[&str; 2]`
```

In order to have `format!` as the first element, I can't use references, but owned values instead:

```rust
foo(&[format!("def {}", 99), "abc".to_owned()]);
```

Why?

Comment: You can cast the `&String` to a `&str`, e.g. `&[&format!("def {}", 99) as &str, "abc"]` or `&[format!("def {}", 99).as_str(), "abc"])`.

Comment: You could also force the deref coercion with`&*format!("def {}", 99)`.

Comment: I can't find the related duplicate answer now, but the TL;DR is that the compiler infers the type of the array based on the *first* element. The working cases it's `&str`, the failing cases it's `&String`. A `&String` can be coerced to a `&str`, but not the other way around. It also won't "backtrack" to change the `&String` to a `&str` and try everything again.

Comment: @Shepmaster That makes perfect sense, and it indeed works. Please make it an answer so I can mark it.